# Magento Promotion Cart Rule Setting - Multiple Free Gifts

Tags: magento, cart, rule

I'm trying to set :
1. Buy every $100 receives free gift A
2. Buy every $200 receives free gift A + B

Is there a way to configure the cart rule?
I tried adding these 2 rules (with 100% discount applied to both products) and put rule#2 with a higher priority. But when there is $300 value in cart, customer is able to get 3pcs of A and 1 pcs of B free --> correct outcome should be only 2pcs of A and 1pcs of B free.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to disable further rules processing after each.